# Save canvas coordinates into local file php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html, canvas

I would like to save my generated canvas to my local file.
I can already display the drawings to my canvas, but after it I don't know how to save its coordinates.

this is what I've got so far

```js
function display() {
 var canvas = document.getElementById('displaycanvas');
 context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    if(document.getElementById('color1').checked){
      context.strokeStyle="#FF0000";
    } else if(document.getElementById('color2').checked){
      context.strokeStyle="#0000FF";
    }
    if (document.getElementById('shape1').checked) {
           context.beginPath();
           context.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
           context.stroke();     }

    if (document.getElementById('shape2').checked) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.rect(50, 27, 50, 100);
            context.stroke();    }
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <form role="form" id="showchoices" name="showchoices" method="post" action="submitorder.php"> 
<canvas id="displaycanvas"></canvas>
<div> <input type="radio" id="shape1" name="shape_design" value="CIRCLE" onchange="display()"/> O 
<input type="radio" id="shape2" name="shape_design" value="RECTANGLE" onchange="display()"/> [] </div>

<div> <input type="radio" id="color1" name="color_design" value="RED" onchange="display()"/> RED  
<input type="radio" id="color2" name="color_design" value="BLUE" onchange="display()"/> BLUE </div>
</form>

<input type="button" name="btn" value="Save Canvas" id="save" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

I already stored the values to my database (radio button choices)

```
<? php

$shape_design = $_POST['shape_design'];
$color_design = $_POST['color_design'];

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
@mysql_select_db('design_DB', $link);

$query1 = "INSERT INTO order_cake (shape_design, color_design) VALUES ('$shape_design' , '$color_design');
?>
```

Now I got the php working, I would like to include the coordinates of the canvas or the canvas itself to save in my local file. I wanted to display it sooner

```
<?php
 $canvas_path = $_POST['']; //the path file to store in my local form, the VARCHAR link can be displayed in database
 $context = $_POST[''];

?>
```

I've been stuck here for how many days, I really need help.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You included the jQuery library, but I don't see you using it. It's called Ajax which is also a great soccer team and that rhymes with, happy Googling.

Comment: I really don't know yet how to use ajax, I just include it there because my template is in bootstraps. I didn't use ajax for submission but only jquery.

Answer (score 0):

As an easy fix, rather than discussing edge cases and data structures, is to simply save the canvas as image-data with [canvas.toDataUrl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)

Then send the text to the server with any of the common methods, like setting the value of a hidden input element to be the image-data string.

`<input hidden name="image-data">`

then, after all of the canvas stuff has been done:

`inputElement.value = canvas.toDataUrl();`

and now it's accessible in PHP:

`$imageData = $_GET['image-data']`

There are various ways to make use of this string now. By setting it to the src of any `<img>`, you'll find out how that it's a valid url that completely encodes the image, and you don't have to look hard to find ways to turn this encoding into anything else you might want, as it's fairly common standard

Comment: thank you! So in your case you suggest that turning it to image is Better than saving it to pure canvas right? ... Actually I did turn my canvas to image `var dataURL = $('#displaycake')[0].toDataURL();` //displaycake is the raw canvas ,  `$("#show_canvas").attr("src", dataURL);` //show_canvas is the image of displaycake canvas,  `$("#show_canvas").show();` //displays the converted image.. , can you help me how can i fix this on how you plan to do it?